# Представить в виде таблицы структуру каталогов

Tags: c#

Есть список структуры каталогов вот пример:

```html
\\машины\
\\дома\
\\люди\
\\машины\синии\
\\машины\красные\
\\дома\синии\
\\дома\красные\
\\машины\синии\большие\
\\машины\красные\большие\
\\дома\синии\большие\
\\дома\красные\большие\
\\машины\синии\маленькие\
\\машины\красные\маленькие\
\\дома\синии\маленькие\
\\дома\красные\маленькие\
```

Необходимо создать таблицу по заданным данным где каждый каталог будет пронумерован и указан его родительский каталог и дочерние к примеру так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это реализовать? Как пройтись по всему списку и разместить результаты потом в таблице? Может подскажете алгоритм. Пытался сделать через деревья, но как потом их обработать не пойму.

Comment: Когда вы пишете "таблица" вы имеете ввиду структуру данных, которая будет поддерживать определенные операции, так? Если так напишите, какие именно операции будут производиться.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Собственно мне так и указано сделать ответ в таблице. Т.е. на входе у тебя вот такой список, а на выходе такая вот табличка.